# Can't cancel the onchange event for my HTML checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working example of this but I'm not sure why my implementation isn't working. Can somebody please help? I'm missing something and I need another set of eyes to find it for me. :)

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wanUF/2/) <-- see code here.

I'm trying to reproduce the functionality used [here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljeosnqv.php). I seem to be a little confused about passing/accessing the `event` variable around.

Thanks!! :-)

Comment: changing onChange to onClick works for me.. strange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to the Click event: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wanUF/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkbox1').click(function(event) {
        if (flag) {
            CancelEvent(event);
            return event.returnValue;
        }
        SomeOtherStuff('this method has real functionality too');
    });
});​
```

Change is a little to late in the event structure to cancel the action that already happened.
In addition, the return value was being omitted. So I added it to the event handler.

Comment: This indeed seems to be my problem. Not sure how I transcribed "onclick" to "onchange". Thanks for pointing that out plus my omission of the return. :)

Comment: No problem, I should mention that in the answer as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `return event.returnValue;` and onClick will work instead of onChange?

http://jsfiddle.net/wanUF/11/

Answer (score 2):

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wanUF/13/).

return false on checkbox click.

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function(event) {

    return false;
});
```

you can either use disabled attribute of input

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" disabled=disabled  />
```

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I'm unable to set it to disabled because I don't know until the moment somebody clicks it whether or not it should be clickable. Lots of async stuff happening and rather than putting a lot of effort into maintaining some really complex state, I'd rather just calculate it real quick on an as-needed basis. But generally, I agree, disabled is good "in-advance feedback" to the user for something like this. Just not this specific application. :)